# Query not returning expected result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
 SELECT * FROM Sales 
 WHERE (Date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-02-28') 
   AND (ID="Search" OR Product="Search");
```

It should return only sales between those 2 dates that have either ID os Product equal search, but it's returning all results that are between those dates even if neither ID or product = Search, and I don't understand why

Edit

Sample Data

```
ID      Date          Product
1       2017-01-11    Product A
2       2017-02-01    Product C
3       2017-02-05    Product B
4       2017-03-01    Product A
```

If my query is

```
SELECT * FROM Sales 
WHERE (Date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-02-28') 
 AND (ID="Product C" OR Product="Product C");
```

I was expecting

```
ID      Date          Product  
2       2017-02-01    Product C
```

But it returns

```
ID      Date          Product  
1       2017-01-11    Product A  
2       2017-02-01    Product C  
3       2017-02-05    Product B
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show some sample data, otherwise we won't be able to understand your problem.

Comment: Your query should return what you expect.  Are you sure you have transcribed the query correctly?

Comment: Are you sure you are saving date column as datetime datatype and not string?

Comment: It's working correctly as far as I can see. All results are between 2017-01-01 and 2017-02-28.

Comment: It should work correctly like you expected, see this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec720/1, is there anything different with your table structure, i.e is the data type of `date` column string instead of date/datetime?

Answer (score 1):

It's no problem with it. for example,

my table

`+----+------+---------------------+
| id | name | create_at           |
+----+------+---------------------+
|  1 |    1 | 2017-03-04 11:06:25 |
|  2 |    2 | 2017-03-04 11:09:27 |
|  3 |    4 | 2017-03-04 11:06:56 |
+----+------+---------------------+`

my sql

`SELECT * FROM test 
WHERE (create_at BETWEEN '2017-03-04 11:06:00' AND '2017-03-04 11:10:00') 
AND (id="2" OR name="2");`

my result

`+----+------+---------------------+
| id | name | create_at           |
+----+------+---------------------+
|  2 |    2 | 2017-03-04 11:09:27 |
+----+------+---------------------+`